# Unable to pass enum value to mutation

Tags: typescript, enums, apollo, apollo-client

I have the following schema definition:

```
enum CommunityType {
  INTEREST
  COMPANY
  INDUSTRY
}
...
extend type Mutation {
  createCommunity(name: String!, type: CommunityType): Community
}
```

And the following mutation:

```
mutation CreateCommunity($name: String!, $type: CommunityType) {
  createCommunity(name: $name, type: $type) {
    id
    name
    type
  }
}
```

Apollo generated the correct TypeScript types for me as well:

```
export interface CreateCommunity_createCommunity {
  __typename: "Community";
  id: string | null;
  name: string | null;
  type: CommunityType | null;
}

export interface CreateCommunity {
  createCommunity: CreateCommunity_createCommunity | null;
}

export interface CreateCommunityVariables {
  name: string;
  type?: CommunityType | null;
}
```

And global types:

```
/**
 * CommunityType
 */
export enum CommunityType {
  COMPANY = "COMPANY",
  INDUSTRY = "INDUSTRY",
  INTEREST = "INTEREST",
  LOCATION = "LOCATION",
  MINISTRY = "MINISTRY",
}
```

When I use the mutation like so

```
 const [create, {
    loading,
    error,
  }] = useMutation<CreateCommunity, CreateCommunityVariables>(CREATE_COMMUNITY, {
    variables: {
      name: title,
      type: CommunityType.COMPANY,
    },
  });
```

I get this error when invoking `create`:

> GraphQL error: Expected a value of type "CommunityType" but received: "company"

It seems like Apollo Client somehow transforms the enum value `COMPANY` to lower case.

I'm using apollo-client `2.6.8`. Edit: I upgraded to apollo-client `3.3.6`, same problem

Comment: Looks like its open as a Github issue: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/7562 as it doesn't seem to be supported yet. Did you find a suitable workaround?